# update a view when a protocol is called

Tags: swift, uiview, protocols

Hello programmers I'm struggling with this.

what I want to do is update a UIView when an API response

like this (on my **MapVC**)

```
    if isUS {
                            if station.name == "AM" || station.name == "Amoco" {
                                imageName = mobileEnabled ? "amocoCircleBrand" : "bpCircleBrand"
                            }
                            WalletService.shared.locateAndCheckinToNearestStore(toExplicitLocation: CLLocation(latitude: station.lat, longitude: station.long)) { storee, error in
                                WalletService.shared.getSiteDetails { siteDetails, error in
                                    let value = siteDetails?.fuelGrades?.first?.price
                                    if value != 0.0 || value != nil {
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
//**this is the part where I have my protocol for update the view**
                                            self?.configure(leftLogoImage: pumpImage ?? UIImage(), topLabelTitle: "title_marker".localized, bottonLabelContent: String(value ?? 0.0), imageBrand: brandImage ?? UIImage())
                                            self?.addMarker(to: station.lat, lon: station.long, image: pumpImage, id: idCounter, addMarkerForPrice: true)
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            self?.addMarker(to: station.lat, lon: station.long, image: pumpImage, id: idCounter, addMarkerForPrice: false)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            //adding false for marker because is US only
                            self?.addMarker(to: station.lat, lon: station.long, image: pumpImage, id: idCounter, addMarkerForPrice: false)
                            path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: station.lat, longitude: station.long))
                        }
```

my reach goal is to change the marker depending the information that comes from the API before calling the Marker function I want to update the view
with this 2 lines this is on the **MapVC**

*note the marker Function*

```
self?.addMarker
```

requires from me a UIView which is the **MarkerView** that I'm trying to update

```
self?.configure(leftLogoImage: pumpImage ?? UIImage(), topLabelTitle: "title_marker".localized, bottonLabelContent: String(value ?? 0.0), imageBrand: brandImage ?? UIImage())
self?.addMarker(to: station.lat, lon: station.long, image: pumpImage, id: idCounter, addMarkerForPrice: true)
                                        }
```

I have a protocol on my marker view for update the view, but doesn't seems to work

```
protocol MarkerViewUSDelegate: AnyObject{
    func configure(leftLogoImage: UIImage, topLabelTitle: String, bottonLabelContent: String, imageBrand: UIImage)
}
```

here's my entire marker view

```
protocol MarkerViewUSDelegate: AnyObject{
    func configure(leftLogoImage: UIImage, topLabelTitle: String, bottonLabelContent: String, imageBrand: UIImage)
}

class MarkerViewUS: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var markerView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftLogo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottonLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var circleBrand: UIImageView!
    weak var delegate: MarkerViewUSDelegate?
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureUI()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configureUI()
    }
    
    private func configureUI() {
        initSubviews()
        delegate?.configure(leftLogoImage: leftLogo.image ?? UIImage(), topLabelTitle: topLabel.text ?? "", bottonLabelContent: bottonLabel.text ?? "", imageBrand: circleBrand.image ?? UIImage())
    }
    
    private func initSubviews() {
        let name = String(describing: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: name, bundle: siteFinderBundle)
        nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
        
        addSubview(self.contentView)
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            self.contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
            self.contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            self.contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
}
```

on my **MapVC** I have implemented the protocol like this:

```
extension StationFinderViewController: MarkerViewUSDelegate {
    func configure(leftLogoImage: UIImage, topLabelTitle: String, bottonLabelContent: String, imageBrand: UIImage) {
        print("")
    }  
}
```

but seems like every time I call the function

```
self?.configure(leftLogoImage: pumpImage ?? UIImage(), topLabelTitle: "title_marker".localized, bottonLabelContent: String(value ?? 0.0), imageBrand: brandImage ?? UIImage())
```

it gets call on the **MapVC** instead if the **markerVC**

**MarkerViewUS** is part of the **MapVC**
it's an empty UIView with the class **MarkerViewUS** so I can re-use this component from the **MarkerView**

```
@IBOutlet weak var usMarker: MarkerViewUS!
```

Comment: Can you share more code, where are you using `MarkerViewUS`?

Comment: Hello @son, I edited the question MArkerViewUS is part of the MapVC as empty UIView with the class of MarkerViewUS
'@IBOutlet weak var usMarker: MarkerViewUS!'

Comment: I guess you're missing kind of `usMarker.delegate = self`. Where `self`, for example, is current the view controller (StationFinderViewController)

Comment: didn't  work I also tried creating a function on MarkerViewUS instead of using protocols 
`func configure(leftLogoImage: UIImage, topLabelTitle: String, bottonLabelContent: String, imageBrand: UIImage) {
        leftLogo.image = leftLogoImage
        topLabel.text = topLabelTitle
        bottonLabel.text = bottonLabelContent
        circleBrand.image = imageBrand
        
    }`

Comment: on the MapVC
`DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        let screen = MarkerViewUS()
                                        screen.configure(leftLogoImage: pumpImage ?? UIImage(), topLabelTitle: "test", bottonLabelContent: "%313", imageBrand: brandImage ?? UIImage())
                                        self?.addMarker(to: station.lat, lon: station.long, image: pumpImage, id: idCounter, addMarkerForPrice: true)
                                    }`

Comment: I didn't get this, so confusing, what is markerVC here?